# Using React dropdown to change separate variable value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to code a React page that will have a drop down of monthly expenses (food, rent, etc.). Goal is that we can make the TransTotal change when the different items are selected from the dropdown. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const products = 
    [
        {id: 0, label: 'rent', quantity: 20, tax: .1, pricePerUnit: 2.25},
        {id: 1, label: 'food', quantity: 10, tax: .1, pricePerUnit: 2.50},
        {id: 2, label: 'other', quantity: 15, tax: .1, pricePerUnit: 3.00}
    ]
;

let row = 0;

class CostDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props){ 
    super(props) 
        
    // Set initial state 
    this.state = {
        transTotal : 0.0
      } 

  } 

  updateTotal() {
    this.setState({transTotal: (quantity, price, tax) => (quantity * price) * (1 + tax)})
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Expense Tracker</h1>
       
        <form>
            <div>
              <h2>Transaction Details</h2>
            </div>
            <label>Cost Item: </label>
            <select name="product" onChange={this.updateTotal.bind(this)}>
                {products.map(({id,label}, index) => 
                <option value={id}>{label}</option> ) }
              </select><br/>
            <label>Quantity:</label> {products[row].quantity}<br/>
            <label>Price per Unit:</label> {products[row].pricePerUnit}<br/>
            <label>Tax:</label> {products[row].tax}<br/>
            <label>Total:</label> {this.state.transTotal}            

        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CostDetail;
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
react-dom.development.js:86 
    
   Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly
```

Comment: Looks more like a warning to me

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would check the version of the ReactDOM. If you copy-paste the above code on an online coding tool (which installs the newest versions) this warning doesn't appear. I personally checked that on codesandbox.io.

At any case, if I may also help towards the solution of the issue you're presenting here, I would suggest to take a closer look on how the `onChange` functions work in general. Those functions receive the `event` as an argument from which you can extract the selected value by accessing the `event.target.value`.

Also, you can take a lot on the React documentation on how the controlled components work (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) which I believe will help you since you need to do some computations based on the selected value.

To take a step further, I took the initiative to provide a working version of your example, just for you to experiment with all those concepts before you can adjust it to your needs.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const products = [
  { id: 0, label: "Choose option", quantity: 0, tax: 0, pricePerUnit: 0 },
  { id: 1, label: "rent", quantity: 20, tax: 0.1, pricePerUnit: 2.25 },
  { id: 2, label: "food", quantity: 10, tax: 0.1, pricePerUnit: 2.5 },
  { id: 3, label: "other", quantity: 15, tax: 0.1, pricePerUnit: 3.0 }
];

function CostDetail() {
  const [transTotal, setTransTotal] = useState(0);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);

  const updateTotal = (event) => {
    const selectedOption = event.target.value;
    const { quantity, pricePerUnit, tax } = products[selectedOption];
    console.log(quantity, pricePerUnit, tax);

    setSelected(selectedOption);
    setTransTotal((quantity * pricePerUnit * (1 + tax)).toFixed(2));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Expense Tracker</h1>

      <form>
        <div>
          <h2>Transaction Details</h2>
        </div>
        <label>Cost Item: </label>
        <select onChange={updateTotal} selected={selected}>
          {products.map(({ id, label }) => (
            <option key={id} value={id}>
              {label}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <br />
        <label>Quantity:</label> {products[selected].quantity}
        <br />
        <label>Price per Unit:</label> {products[selected].pricePerUnit}
        <br />
        <label>Tax:</label> {products[selected].tax}
        <br />
        <label>Total:</label> {transTotal}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CostDetail;
```